# Error installing hadoop-3.1.4 'hdfs' not reconginzed

Tags: hadoop

I am tring to install Hadoop in my windows machine, but when I run the command:
hdfs namenode -format

I get below error

[image]

I have correctly set enviroment variables:
JDK location: C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin
Hadoop location: C:\Hadoop\hadoop-3.1.4\hadoop-3.1.4\bin

[image]

Any idea why would I be still getting error ?
I tried re-installing jave & hadoop but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I got this resolved.
The issue was with the hadoop bin directory.
The bin that needs to be replaced with default bin directory had an extra directory created:
Incorrect: C:\Hadoop\hadoop-3.1.4\hadoop-3.1.4\bin\bin

After deleting extra bin directroty:
C:\Hadoop\hadoop-3.1.4\hadoop-3.1.4\bin

This got the issue resolved.